# search in procedures/functions in all dbs for a table usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

So, it is a Sql Server 2008, with a lot of databases, and i need to find all  usages in everyone of them(dbs) for a specific table.
Can somebody point me a direction to do that?

Comment: Not really a question for SO however i would recommend SQL search by redgate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the variable @TableToSearchFor equal to the table you're after.  The undocumented system stored procedure `sp_MSforeachdb` will iterate the statement across all the DB's on your server.

```
DECLARE @TableToSearchFor nvarchar(max)
SET @TableToSearchFor = 'YourTableName'


DECLARE @MySearchStatement nvarchar(max)
SET @MySearchStatement = 
'USE [?]; '  +
'SELECT DISTINCT ' + 
'   DB_Name() AS [DB], ' + 
'   [SysObjects].name AS [Object Name], ' + 
'   [SysObjects].type_desc AS [Type Desc] ' + 
'FROM sys.sql_modules Modules ' + 
'   INNER JOIN sys.objects [SysObjects] ON Modules.object_id = [SysObjects].object_id ' + 
'WHERE  ' + 
'   Modules.[definition] LIKE ''%' + @TableToSearchFor + '%'' ' 


EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @MySearchStatement
```